# Cannot update Amazon Prime app on my PS3

Tags: ps3

I downloaded the Amazon Prime app on my PS3 from the PlayStation Store India. It installed as Amazon Instant Video and when I launch the app it asks me to update to the latest 4.06 update. If I try to update, the estimated time to download keeps increasing and eventually times out without downloading a single KB. If I cancel the update and try to run the Amazon Instant Video app it fails with a message telling me there is no internet connection.

The internet is working fine and I'm able to use YouTube, TuneIn Radio, Netflix, etc. without any issues.

I've tried deleting the app and downloading again, disabling Media Servers, etc.

Any suggestions on how to get th Amazon Prime app to work?

Comment: Its possible that Amazon ended the Playstation 3 support. Its been 5 years since the PS4's launch after all.

Comment: Amazon prime app is working fine for me. Please try to remove the app and install again.

Comment: I got it to work after trying to install it at least 15 times.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the problem was, but after trying to install for a bout 15 time, it finally worked.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/272953)

Comment: @LinusJuhlin He *is* the author, and he's saying that his problem was resolved with an unknown solution.

Comment: @TimS. Yes, I am aware of that. But it still does not provide a solution to others whom are having this issue too. An edit of his original post or a comment would be better in my opinion.

Comment: As unusual or unconventional of a solution it is, it in fact *does* appear to provide a solution. The OP says "I did X to resolve the issue." What else do you call that? I don't think an edit of the original post is out of order, but I disagree with your statement about it not providing an answer. It might not be everyone else's solution, but it clearly worked for the OP. This is why multiple answers can be given, because sometimes there is more than one valid solution.